# sklearn: Can't assign "С" parameter in "sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression"

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am trying to set value for "С" parameter for LogisticRegression doing this:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression 
clf =LogisticRegression(penalty='l2') 
clf.set_params(C,1.0)
```

But i get this: "NameError: name 'C' is not defined"

What is the problem? Why parameter "C" isn't assigned?

Answer (score 1):

```
params = {"C":1.0}
clf.set_params(**params)
```

or

```
clf.set_params(C=1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the dot operator:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
clf =LogisticRegression(penalty='l2')
clf.C = 100
clf
```